# How to retrieve the earliest record with a specific value change in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains change log data, and I want to retrieve the earliest entry where a user made a change to the URL. Rows where the URL value did not change or are null should not be displayed in the result.

Here's an example of my table:

```
| ID      | Name           | URL               | valid_from       | valid_till       | User_Id |
| ------- | -------------- | ----------------- | ---------------- | ---------------- | ------- |
| 1111111 | Max Mustermann |                   | 16.09.2022 08:30 | 20.09.2022 14:15 | 21      |
| 1111111 | Max Mustermann |                   | 20.09.2022 14:15 | 22.09.2022 18:45 | 21      |
| 1111111 | Max Mustermann |                   | 22.09.2022 18:45 | 25.09.2022 09:00 | 999     |
| 1111111 | Max Mustermann | maxmuster.com     | 25.09.2022 09:00 | 01.10.2022 17:30 | 21      |
| 1111111 | Max Mustermann | maxmustermann.com | 01.10.2022 17:30 | 05.10.2022 12:00 | 777     |
| 1111111 | Max Mustermann | max.com           | 05.10.2022 12:00 |                  | 777     |
| 2121212 | Alexa Mueller  | alexa-mueller.com | 10.10.2022 20:45 | 15.10.2022 06:15 | 21      |
| 2121212 | Alexa Mueller  | alexamueller.com  | 15.10.2022 06:15 | 20.10.2022 16:30 | 999     |
| 2121212 | Alexa Mueller  | alexamueller.com  | 20.10.2022 16:30 |                  | 999     |
```

And here's what I want the result to look like:

```
| ID      | URL               | valid_from       | User_id |
| ------- | ----------------- | ---------------- | ------- |
| 1111111 | maxmuster.com     | 25.09.2022 09:00 | 21      |
| 1111111 | maxmustermann.com | 01.10.2022 17:30 | 777     |
| 1111111 | max.com           | 05.10.2022 12:00 | 777     |
| 2121212 | alexa-mueller.com | 10.10.2022 20:45 | 21      |
| 2121212 | alexamueller.com  | 15.10.2022 06:15 | 999     |
```

Edit:

I tried following, the problem is that even though it shows all changes. It doesn't display the right valid_from value.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
        id,
        url,
        first_value(valid_from) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY valid_from) as valid_from,
        first_value([User_id]) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY valid_from DESC) as [User_id],
    FROM 
        changelog
    WHERE 
        url IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY id, valid_from ASC
```

Comment: Have a search of "gaps and islands" problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to retrieve the earliest record with a specific value change in
> SQL

Here's an example query that should provide what you want to:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.URL, t1.valid_from, t1.User_Id
FROM your_table t1
JOIN (
  SELECT ID, URL, MIN(valid_from) AS min_valid_from
  FROM your_table
  WHERE URL IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY ID, URL
) t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.URL = t2.URL AND t1.valid_from = t2.min_valid_from
```

Here is how it works?

1. Using the **MIN function** and a **GROUP BY clause**, the **subquery** obtains the **minimum valid_from value** for each **distinct ID** and **URL** combination. This allows us to extract the oldest row in each group and effectively combines together all rows where the URL value changed into a single group.
2. The main query joins the original table with the subquery on three conditions:
   **ID must match**, **URL must match**, and **valid_from** must equal the **minimum valid_from value** calculated in the subquery. This ensures that we only retrieve the earliest row in each group where the URL value changed, while also retrieving the other columns we're interested in **(URL and User_Id)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `ROW_NUMBER` to get the first row in every group.

```sql
WITH Numbered AS (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, URL ORDER BY valid_from)
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE URL IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM Numbered
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/Zv1Gw43M)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry my example is misleading, ideally the query does not only look at previous row. It should check all changes made to URL.

Comment: Then use `row_number` see edit

Comment: @jonas: the solution using window function is almost always more efficient than self-join and subqueries. This is the right way to solve your question.